# Is there a list of reserved words for Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a documented list of keywords for Cloud Spanner?

For example, is CONTAINS a reserved word?

Comment: have you googled for that? https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#reserved_keywords

Comment: The list of reserved words is not at that url.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous answer, the link doesn't navigate correctly here is the correct link:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved_keywords

(it should be `reserved_keywords` in the instead of `reserved-keywords`)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a list of keywords, documented at [Reserved Keywords](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/lexical#reserved-keywords).